# Angular 6 Caching with Http Interceptor - Map operator in code somehow mutates cached HttpResponse

Tags: angular, caching, angular-http-interceptors

I recently got a cache working in my Angular 6 app using an HttpInterceptor. It records responses in memory and serves them if they exist with a TTL. However I have a problem where the program code which makes the Http requests uses the map operator to modify the data retrieved, this somehow is getting saved to the cache. How can I make it so my cached HttpResponse objects are not mutated in any way after retrieving them from the server and storing them in the cache?

I've created a stackblitz that demonstrates the issue:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caching-mutation

When the response is served from the cache, it will be split into an array already, as if the map operation happened before the server response was saved to the cache.

Fetcher service making HTTP Call and mutating response:

```
getData() {
return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .pipe(map(next => {
    next['title'] = next['title'].split('u');
    return next;
  }));;
}
```

Interceptor:

```
const TTL = 5;

@Injectable()
export class CacheInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private cache: GetCacheService) {
  }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (!(request.method === 'GET')) {
      return next.handle(request);
    } else {
      console.log('Checking cache for data.');
      const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(request.url);
      return cachedResponse ? of(cachedResponse) : this.handleRequest(request, next);
    }
  }

  private handleRequest(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ) {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(event => {

      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.cache.set(request.url, event, TTL);
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

Caching Service:

```
@Injectable({
              providedIn: 'root'
            })
export class GetCacheService {
  private cache = new Map<string, [Date, HttpResponse<any>]>();

  constructor() {
  }

  get(key: string): HttpResponse<any> {
    const tuple = this.cache.get(key);
    if (!tuple) {
      return null;
    }

    const expires = tuple[0];
    const httpResponse = tuple[1];

    // check if cached HttpResponse is expired, if it is, delete
    // it and respond as if we had nothing cached
    const now = new Date();
    if (expires && expires.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
      this.cache.delete(key);
      return null;
    }
    console.log('Retrieved from cache!');
    console.log(httpResponse);
    console.log('The above cached HttpResponse object has been mutated by the mapping function in fetcher.service.ts');
    return httpResponse;
  }

  set(key: string, value: HttpResponse<any>, ttl = null) {
    if (ttl) {
      const expires = new Date();
      expires.setSeconds(expires.getSeconds() + ttl);
      this.cache.set(key, [expires, value]);
    } else {
      this.cache.set(key, [null, value]);
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Cache Service, get()

You are returning the original cache object which refers to same object instance and it will mutate if modify it. You can use this code

```
get(key: string): HttpResponse<any> {
   .....
   return Object.assign({}, httpResponse);
}
```

Comment: I understand doing some kind of deep copy on the HttpResponse object before storing or returning it may work, but I did not have success using Object.assign({}, httpResponse) to do so.

Comment: use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(httpResponse)) instead then